# Batch script to delete same name files with appended numbers

Tags: batch-file

I'm working on creating a batch script which will allow me delete files with the same name and an appended ascending number; for example:

```
fileName.txt 
fileName (1).txt 
fileName (2).txt
fileName (3).txt
fileName (4).txt
fileName (5).txt
fileName (6).txt
fileName (7).txt
etc....
```

Below is the code I came up with, but it only deletes the file name, without the appended number in the parenthesis.

```bash
@echo off
:: Change to the Downloads directory
cd %UserProfile%\Downloads
:: Deletes files
Del Awesome-Kicks-Test_File-Run.txt
```

All of these file are saved in my `Downloads` directory.

Could you please direct me on how best to go about deleting these files?

Comment: There are already many examples posted here on SO. Did you try the search yet?

Answer (score -1):

Since you are on Windows, you should have access to PowerShell. PS has much better support for these types of operations, and is available on all versions of Windows in common use.

One method is to use a regular expression to find all of the files that match the pattern. Here is a basic one that should work for the example you gave: `fileName \(\d+\)`

Using PowerShell, you then combine that regular expression with the `Get-ChildItem`, `Where-Object` and `Remove-Item` commandlets.

```
Get-ChildItem | Where-Object { $_.Name -match 'fileName \(\d+\)' } | Remove-Item
```